# Forbidden (co)end calculus tricks: why are they so effective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, recreational-mathematics

I've been toying around with (co)ends a lot lately. I tried a lot of things, and many seem to work pretty well. As an example, I computed the end $\int_{X:\mathtt{Set}}X$ using the following chain of nonsensical isomorphisms for every set $Y$ :
$$\begin{aligned}\mathtt{Set}\left(Y, \int_{X:\mathtt{Set}}X\right)& \simeq \int_{X:\mathtt{Set}}\mathtt{Set}(Y,X) \\ 
& \simeq \int_{X:\mathtt{Set}}\mathtt{Set}\left(\{\star\}, \mathtt{Set}(Y,X)\right) \\ 
& \simeq \int_{X:\mathtt{Set}}\mathtt{Set}\left(\mathtt{Set}(\emptyset, X), \mathtt{Set}(Y, X)\right) \\ 
&\simeq \mathtt{Set}^{\mathtt{Set}}\left(\mathtt{Set}(\emptyset, \cdot), \mathtt{Set}(Y, \cdot)\right) \\ 
\mathtt{Set}\left(Y, \int_{X:\mathtt{Set}}X\right)& \simeq \mathtt{Set}(Y, \emptyset)\end{aligned}$$
which by Yoneda wields $\int_{X:\mathtt{Set}}X\simeq \emptyset$. This is no surprise, as the end has an arrow to every set, including the empty set.
Similarly, we can compute the coend $\int^{X:\mathtt{Set}}X$ :
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathtt{Set}\left(\int^{X:\mathtt{Set}}X, Y\right) & \simeq \int_{X:\mathtt{Set}}\mathtt{Set}(X,Y) \\
& \simeq \int_{X:\mathtt{Set}}\mathtt{Set}\left(\mathtt{Set}(\{\star\}, X), Y\right) \\
& \simeq \mathtt{Set}^\mathtt{Set}\left(\mathtt{Set}(\{\star\}, \cdot), Y\right) \\
& \simeq Y \\ 
\mathtt{Set}\left(\int^{X:\mathtt{Set}}X, Y\right) & \simeq \mathtt{Set}(\{\star\}, Y)
\end{aligned}$$
which by Yoneda yields $\int^{X:\mathtt{Set}}X\simeq \{\star\}$.

I know I'm either lucky or wrong (and I'm at least as wrong as there are size issues), but why does it seem to work so well? Are there some other cool computations or tricks one can use?

Comment: What makes you think these isomorphisms are nonsensical? There aren't as many size issues as you might think -- Set is complete, so every small end exists, but that doesn't mean non-small ends can't exist. They just are not constructible internally to Set via an equalizer diagram.

Comment: I think the biggest problem with this whole setup is that it's not clear which profunctor you're taking the end of. I think you're really taking a limit in disguise (indeed the limit of the identity functor C → C is the initial object of C whenever it exists).

Comment: Set isn't small... I'm not sure I can use the "natural transformation formula". And I just got lucky to find those, I still can't solve many toy examples I tried...

update: Thanks! I must admit that I'm not really at ease with size issues! I knew that if an initial element existed, that kind of end had to exist, but I didn't think of it as a limit of the identity functor.

Comment: I like this idea that there are "forbidden techniques". :-)

Comment: @fosco perhaps the name for a secret, unpublished appendix to your book?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necronomicon#Fictional_history ...and with strange eons even ends may die

Comment: @chaotic You might like to prove that $\int_i F i = \varprojlim_i F i$ and $\int^i F i = \varinjlim_i F i$.